# Strings stick to pickup poles when the tremolo is depressed.

Tags: guitar, maintenance, strings, tremolo-system

Sometimes, when I depress the tremolo quite far, the strings magnetically stick to the pickup poles...

Is this normal? Is there a way I can prevent it, aside from not depressing the tremolo so far?

I've seen artists push down really hard on their tremolos seemingly without having their strings stick to the pickups.

Is there any danger of damaging the strings or pickups?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do; raise the action of the strings; this might not be ideal for you.  So the better option is to lower the height of your pickups;  most pickups are height adjustable using the screws on either side of them.

Ensure you have identified the correct screws before attempting this, and go slow don't try and force the screws.

There is no danger of damaging the strings or pickups from the magnetism; they may make some odd sounds though when you let go of the tremolo.

Here is an article detailing how pickup hieght might affect your tone; for better or for worse.
[Gibson Tone Tips: Pickup Heights](http://www.gibson.com/en-us/Lifestyle/Features/Tone%20Tips_%20Pickup%20Heights/)